# Allowing Google Scripts to skip undefined arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I have a bunch of arrays in my Google Sheets Script in which some contains shares.count; however some don't

```
 feeds.getRange(j+2,8+(i*7),1,1).setValue(response_json.data[j].shares.count);
```

This unfortunately throws an error for those who does not, I've tried writing an if statement in:

```
    if(response_json.data[j].shares.count != 'undefined')
{feeds.getRange(j+2,8+(i*7),1,1).setValue(response_json.data[j].shares.count);}
```

However, I'm still not getting luck.

What would be the best method for getting Google Scripts to identify missing arrays or undefined?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Un what part are you getting the undefined error? Cause shares.count suggests a number (which could be 0). Without knowing what exists and what not, you can check for existence of the property chain before you are trying to modify it, just to play it safe.

```
if(response_json && response_json.data[j] && response_json.data[j].shares && response_json.data[j].shares.count) {
    // now do something
}
```

Comment: Some arrays contains shares.count and some don't at all. It's interesting that if it's 0, the json simply excludes that node.